# jQuery ajax request - prevent overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm calling a function using the jQuery ajax function for calling a webservice in an interval of milliseconds. If one of the first request is slower they are overflapping and the success function will do work with an old requests response.

Here is my ajax calling function:

```
function runRequest(url, request, token, handleSuccess, handleError) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(request),
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(/* ... */),
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            handleSuccess(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            handleError(xhr);
        }
    });
}
```

How to prevent that? I tried to save the time on creation of a request, managed that time to the success and error function to check it if the response is incoming but it won't work..

Synchronized ajax request is no option.. :/

Comment: PS: I don't need to process the requests came to late - i wanna throw them away and use only the newest.

Comment: add a argument to your runRequest function, for example, index, and have a global count variable to denote last index value, and before doing handleSuccess, check if the index value is equal to global count value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way to solve this would be to add a timestamp or counter to your request and update it when you `handleSuccess`.

```
handleSuccess = (function () {
    // closure scope this variable so only handleSuccess sees it.
    var latest = 0;
    return function handleSuccess(timestamp, data) {
        if (timestamp < latest) { return; }
        latest = timestamp;
        // the normal body of handleSuccess goes here
    };
})();
function runRequest(url, request, token, handleSuccess, handleError) {
    var timestamp = (new Date()).valueOf();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(request),
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(/* ... */),
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            handleSuccess(timestamp, data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            handleError(xhr);
        }
    });
}
```

You can see the way that the handleSuccess wrapper works in this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/n6j1psut/

Comment: Sorry for the late marking as solved. Thanks Ian, this was the only answer without the maximum number limit :)

Answer (score 1):

As I have commented:

```
var count = 0;
function runRequest(url, request, token, handleSuccess, handleError, index) {
    count = index;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(request),
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(/* ... */),
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            if(index == count){
                handleSuccess(data);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            if(index == count){
                handleError(xhr);
            }
        }
    });
}

runRequest(..., count++);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if you already in progress and wait until it finish for example:

```
var isRunning = false;

function call()
{
     if(isRunning)
      return; // still working... please wait.
     isRunning = true;

    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(request),
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(/* ... */),
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                handleSuccess(data);
                isRunning = false;
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                handleError(xhr);
                isRunning = false;
            }
        });
  }
```

Comment: Sorry - my comment came to late on my post.. I don't need all of them, just the one which was send at last..

Comment: Sending: 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
Incoming:  1  3  2  4  5  8  6  7  9  10
Processing:  1  3  -  4  5  8  -  -  9  10

Comment: you enter to dead zone, when you making the request is almost impossible to drop it after the transmission, only the server side can reject them, but it will failed to know what packet is relative and what are not..